# Singleton PDO Model - Hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, singleton, pdo

Sorry for poor english, I'm Brazilian, and even worse talking about programming.
Let's go. I have this:

```
class DataBase extends PDO
{

/**
 * @var object PDO
 */
private static $instance;


/**
 * Cria uma instância do PDO representando a conexão ao banco de dados e torna a instância disponível como "singleton"
 *
 * @param string $dsn            O DSN completo, ex.: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb
 * @param string $username       O nome de usuário para a string DSN. Esse parâmetro é opcional para alguns drivers do PDO.
 * @param string $password       A senha para a string DSN. Esse parâmetro é opcional para alguns drivers do PDO.
 * @param array  $driver_options Um array key => value de opções de conexão específicas do driver
 *
 * @return PDO
 */
public
function __construct()
{

    global $config;

    $dsn      = "mysql:dbname={$config['database'][AMBIENTE]['banco']};host={$config['database'][AMBIENTE]['url']}";
    $username = $config['database'][AMBIENTE]['usuario'];
    $password = $config['database'][AMBIENTE]['senha'];

    if ( !isset ( self::$instance ) )
    {
        try
        {
            self::$instance = parent::__construct( $dsn , $username , $password );
        }
        catch ( PDOException $e )
        {
            Functions::Log( 'Erro de conexão de banco de dados: ' . $e->getMessage() );
            header( 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error' );
        }
    }

    $this->storage = new ArrayObject();

}

public static
function getInstance()
{
    if ( !self::$instance )
    {
        self::$instance = new DataBase;
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

 }
```

and the model that extends the class DataBase:

```
class Model extends DataBase
{
protected $TABLE_NAME;
protected $TABLE_PREFIX;
/* all logic here, like getters, setters and methods like update, delete and insert... */
}
```

But I can't use the $this variable to access the PDO methods like query OR prepare. It's says that I'm not called the PDO constructor, even if my Model class constructor call getInstance.

It's possible?

Comment: Why is your Database constructor public?

Comment: check self::$instance. This is where your problem is. If you need a code example let me know.

Comment: Can you @busypeoples enlighten my errors? I thought that all magic methods should be public by default. I would like to have an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your example work, you might try this.

```
define('DB_CONN','mysql:dbname=;host=');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASS', '');

interface iMySQL
{

    public
    function query( $string );

    public
    function select();

    public
    function selectAll();

    public
    function insert();

    public
    function update();

    public
    function delete();

    public
    function load();

}



class DataBase
{

    /**
     * @var object PDO
     */
    private static $instance = null;


    /**
     * Cria uma instância do PDO representando a conexão ao banco de dados e torna a instância disponível como "singleton"
     *
     * @param string $dsn            O DSN completo, ex.: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb
     * @param string $username       O nome de usuário para a string DSN. Esse parâmetro é opcional para alguns drivers do PDO.
     * @param string $password       A senha para a string DSN. Esse parâmetro é opcional para alguns drivers do PDO.
     * @param array  $driver_options Um array key => value de opções de conexão específicas do driver
     *
     */
    private function __construct() {

    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if ( self::$instance === null )
        {
            self::$instance = new PDO(DB_CONN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

}

class Model
{
    protected $TABLE_NAME;
    protected $TABLE_PREFIX;
    protected $clausula;

    private $storage;

    /**
     * Recupera um registro utilizando sua chave
     *
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return mixed O valor armazenado
     * @throws RuntimeException Se não houver um registro para a chave especificada
     */
    public
    function __get( $key )
    {

    }

    /**
     * Registra um valor à uma chave
     *
     * @param string $key   A chave que será utilizada no registro
     * @param mixed  $value O valor que será registrado
     *
     * @throws LogicException Se a chave já estiver registrada
     */
    public
    function __set( $key , $value )
    {
        //echo $key;
    }


    public static
    function __callStatic( $method , $args )
    {

        $database = DataBase::getInstance();
        $callback = array( $database , $method );
        return call_user_func_array( $callback , $args );

    }

    public
    function __call( $method , $args )
    {

        $database = DataBase::getInstance();
        $callback = array( $database , $method );
        return call_user_func_array( $callback , $args );

    }

    public function __construct( $table_name = null , $id = null )
    {

        $this->TABLE_PREFIX = $this->config['database']['table_prefix'];
        $this->TABLE_NAME   = $this->TABLE_PREFIX . $table_name;

        $this->storage = new ArrayObject();

        if ( !is_null( $table_name ) )
        {
            $array = $this->query( "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$this->TABLE_NAME`" )->fetchAll();

            $colunas      = array();
            $obrigatorias = array();

            foreach ( $array as $value )
            {
                $colunas[] = $value[0];
                if ( $value['Null'] === 'NO' )
                {
                    $obrigatorias[] = $value['Field'];
                }
            }

            $this->colunas       = $colunas;
            $this->obrigatorias  = $obrigatorias;
            $this->total_colunas = count( $this->colunas );

            // Se passou um id por parâmetro, salva nas propriedades do objeto
            if ( !is_null( $id ) AND is_numeric( $id ) )
            {
                $this->id = $id;

                // E já carrega o objeto
                $select = $this->query( 'SELECT * FROM {tabela_nome} WHERE `id` = ' . $id )->fetchObject();
                $this->load( $select );
            }
        }

    }

    public
    function insert()
    {
    }

    public
    function update()
    {
    }

    public
    function delete()
    {
    }

    public
    function select( $clausula = NULL , $is_array = FALSE )
    {
        // Caso seja passado uma cláusula diretamente para a função, executa ela
        if ( !is_null( $clausula ) )
        {
            $this->clausula = $clausula;
        }

        // Troca uma possível variável pelo nome da tabela do Model
        $this->clausula = ( str_replace( '{TABLE_NAME}' , $this->TABLE_NAME , $this->clausula ) );
        $this->clausula = ( str_replace( '{TABLE_PREFIX}' , $this->TABLE_PREFIX , $this->clausula ) );

        // Executa o SELECT no banco de dados
        $query = $this->query( $this->clausula );

        if ( $query AND $query->rowCount() > 0 )
        {

            if ( $query->rowCount() == 1 AND !$is_array )
            {
                return $query->fetchObject( get_class( $this ) );
            }
            else
            {
                $objetos = array();
                while ( $linha = $query->fetchObject( get_class( $this ) ) )
                {
                    $objetos[] = $linha;
                }
                return ( count( $objetos ) > 0 ) ? $objetos : FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public
    function selectAll()
    {
    }

    public
    function load()
    {
    }
}



$model = new Model();
$stmt = $model->query();
$fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($fetch);
```

This is not tested. But it should give you an idea how to solve the problem. 
Try this approach.

```
define('DB_TYPE', 'DB_Class_One');


class DB_Class_One extends PDO {
    public function getData() {
        print 'Class One';
    }
}

class DB_Class_Two extends PDO {
   public function getData() {
        print 'Class Two';
    }
}

class DB_Class_Three extends PDO {
   public function getData() {
        print 'Class Three';
    }
}

class DataBase {

    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    private function __clone() {

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        $class = DB_TYPE;

        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new $class("mysql:host=;dbname=", '', '');
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


}




$db = DataBase::getInstance();

$stmt = $db->query();

$result = $stmt->fetch();

$db->getData();
```

Comment: Depending of my tryings, I get "No PDO construct was called" or "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'DataBase' does not have a method 'query'" ALWAYS.

Full code are shown here: http://pastebin.com/BwPvh3mV

Comment: Don't extend the core class. Try to make the classes as independent as possible. Create a registry and add all the core variables. Or create a config file, and use define() to set all the configuration data. Have you tried the approach above. I have tested it now, it will work.

Comment: sorry for troubling you @busypeoples. I still cannot use $this->method on my Model, extending it or not DataBase class.

Can you write a correct class for me? I can make a payment through PayPal for you.

Comment: @LucasFerreiraFreitas I will try to find a solution. But you have to finish writing the class by yourself or you will run into more problems later on. I will have a look at your code. My example is very similar, but easier to update.

Comment: @LucasFerreiraFreitas in getInstance change -> self::$instance = new DataBase  to this -> self::$instance = new PDO( $dsn , $username , $password );

Comment: thank you very much! I managed to work with this code, but when using JetBrains PHPStorm I don't have code completion (IntelliSense) on my model like: $model = new Model('mytable'); $model->(should appear the PDO methods). I'm assuming that is impossible.

Comment: I'm glad you helped me out, i'm really appreciated. Did a research and found that adding /** @var $dbh PDO */ magic line to my PHPDoc constructor the model acted like a PDO instance!

Answer (score 0):

Something seems funny about your `getInstance()` method *and* your constructor both assigning to `self::$instance`:

```
function getInstance()
{
    if ( !self::$instance )
    {
        self::$instance = new DataBase;
    }

/* .... */

function __construct()
{

/* .... */

    if ( !isset ( self::$instance ) )
    {
        try
        {
            self::$instance = parent::__construct( $dsn , $username , $password );
        }
```

Remove the assignment from `getInstance()` and see if that works.

Comment: It's a singleton PDO wrapper. I thought I could use a Model just by extending this DataBase class, but it's not working. The best approach at this moment is to use __call to forward calls to the $instance property that is where a PDO instance is stored. But $this->query() doesn't work.

Comment: There's a way to fake IDE's to code completion my model class into thinking it's a PDO? I would like to use inside Model class $this->que (popup query)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't bothered setting up any autocompletion bits in `vim`, my editor of choice.

Comment: If anyone here wants to hack their IDE autocomplete, just add something like:
/** @var $varname Class|type */